# Polylineの図芯の求め方について

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD 2018 STD Standaloneで、カスタマイズコマンドを開発しているものです。

質問内容：
Polylineの図芯の位置がプロパティから、あるいはマス・プロパティから取得できないのでしょうか？
オブジェクト・スナップでは指示できるので、取得する方法があると期待しています。面積は取得できていますが、図芯が取得できないので、LineとArcに展開して、求めていますが、処理に数秒の時間が掛かっています。
以上、お願いします。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　このサイトはIJCADに限らずプログラミングに関する質問が投稿される公開のQ&Aサイトになっています。今回のご質問内容自体は全く問題ないのですが、投稿内容にシリアルコードなどが含まれていたため、一旦その部分を削除編集し、編集履歴からも除かせて頂きました。現状誰からも元々の情報を確認することはできなくなっているのでご安心ください。その上でもしこのサイトの使い方について他にご質問がありましたら、[メタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)という場所にて質問できますのでご投稿頂けたらと思います。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

ポリラインをリージョンに変換して、AreaPropertiesメソッドを使用することで図心などの値を取得できますが、どうやらIJCADのReginクラスには上記のメソッドが実装されていないようです。
他の方法としては、GetObjectSnapPointsメソッドを使用して図心にスナップされた場合の座標を取得することも可能です。
ただ、.NET APIのObjectSnapModes列挙型にはARXのAcDb::kOsModeCentroidにあたる値がありませんので、

```
pline.GetObjectSnapPoints((ObjectSnapModes)11, 0, res.PickedPoint, Point3d.Origin, Matrix3d.Identity, snapPts, geoIds);
```

の様にしてメソッドを使用する必要があります。